# Tfs 2017 retrieve test cases run status history

Tags: api, history

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the the history of pass/fail of a test case. I know that tfs has the history of the runs and the status of each test case (this information is visible in the tfs wep page). I want to get this information using the API. Any idea?

E.g.:
Test case Name: Close(x) - i want to see the status of the previous 10 runs. In TFS webapp we have this information:
[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H70dK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API to get the test case and Test Run list, but it's difficult to get the test run history (previous 10 runs here) for the specific test case, unless you run only the specific test case each time (commonly, we will run multiple test cases in a test run).

[REST API to get the test case](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/cases#get-a-test-case), eg:

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/2017ScrumProjectFromVS/_apis/test/plans/105/suites/106/testcases/107?api-version=1.0
```

[REST API to get the test run list](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/runs#get-a-list-of-test-runs) :

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/2017ScrumProjectFromVS/_apis/test/Runs/
```

The best way to retrieve test cases run status history is using MTM (Microsoft Test Manager):

Connect TFS server -->> Select the Team Project -->> Select  **Test** tab >> Select the test plan -->> Select the specific test case -->> **View Results** -->> At the end of the opened page you will see the result history (All test runs for the specific test case).

[image]